# Slow Boot time on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: boot, 64-bit, 15.10

The computer has recently been switched from Windows XP to Ubuntu and although it is faster it isn't as fast as I had expected.

The computer has:

Ubuntu 15.10 64bit

2x1GB of 667MHZ DDR2 Ram

320GB HDD (less than 70GB used)

Nvidia GeForce 8500 GT (512MB)

Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E8500 @ 3.16GHz × 2

A boot chart has been attached to help.
[Boot chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74S8p.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for sharing useful hardware specifications.
Unfortunately you are having very "dated" hardware.
Most relevant is the very small amount of the RAM.
This is the main reason why the boot time is slow.

More important is the overall performance of the system.
You should consider to install the light-weight Xubuntu.
Alternatively you can replace the 2x1 GB with 2x2 GB.
But it is not really recommended for this "old" PC.

Comment: The answer helps but I wandered if there is anything in the boot that might be slowing it down on the attached boot chart image or if it is just that the hardware is too old.

Comment: @UbuntuUser789 : No - when it boots to a working desktop there is nothing wrong - it's just the old hardware ... and there is no fast SSD, but an old HDD built in as well. :)

Comment: Are any of these start-up  items unusual/ unnecessary:
13.661s gpu-manager.service
11.215s accounts-daemon.service
10.749s dev-sda1.device
8.354s plymouth-quit-wait.service
7.239s apparmor.service
6.863s ModemManager.service
6.168s binfmt-support.service
5.542s alsa-restore.service
5.522s speech-dispatcher.service
5.522s systemd-user-sessions.service
5.492s systemd-logind.service
5.449s irqbalance.service
5.449s apport.service
5.447s pppd-dns.service
5.446s grub-common.service
5.444s ondemand.service
5.438s thermald.service
5.437s rsyslog.service
5.436s NetworkManager.service

Comment: @UbuntuUser789 : All these services are usual and necessary to make the system working properly. :)

Comment: @UbuntuUser789: I concur with above.  the only thing you can do is `sudo apt-get install bootchart` and [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) like [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/574515/bootchart-statistics) and then we can go in deeper detail (after you've accepted this one by clicking the ☑ on the left of this answer)  **;-)**